# A Shiny event that gets triggered when plots are finished rendering

Tags: javascript, r, plot, shiny, reactive-programming

Basically I want to observe an event which will trigger when plots of one shiny dashboard tab are finished rendering. The use of this is for hiding an overlying loading page element.

I currently use this:

```
observeEvent("plot", hide(id = "loading-content", anim = TRUE, animType = "fade"))
```

But when I observe a plot the hiding of a loading page triggers when the calculations are ready, not when I get my plot rendered. This is especially bugging me with a multi tab dashboard I am currently working on.

Is there like an even that I could observe which will trigger when the plots in a tab are fully rendered? Something like web browser telling R "Hey I finished with rendering a plot!"

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll want to do this on the client side instead, using [JavaScript events in Shiny](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-events.html). See the section on Output Events.

You may also be interested in https://github.com/andrewsali/shinycssloaders, a library for adding spinners to outputs. If not to use directly, maybe as an example of how to use Shiny's JS events - https://github.com/andrewsali/shinycssloaders/blob/master/inst/assets/spinner.js